# Program doesn't continue reading text file

Tags: python, python-3.7

I want to read data form file a_flag
So I have function here

```py
def get_answer():
    print("Creating r_flag data... ", end="")
    r_flag = Flag(open("request.flg", "r+"))
    print("Done")
    print("Creating a_flag data... ", end="")
    a_flag = Flag(open("answer.flg", "r+"))
    print("Done")
    print("Creating b_flag data... ", end="")
    b_flag = Flag(open("busy.flg", "r+"))
    print("Done")

    # Wait until ready
    print("Getting b_flag data... ", end="")
    b_flag.get_data()
    while b_flag.buffer[1] == 3:
        b_flag.get_data()
    print("Done")
    # Request data
    print("Set r_flag to REQUESTED... ", end="")
    r_flag.set_stat([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
    print("Done")
    print("Now enter looping... ", end="")

    while True:
        print("Done")
        print("  Getting a_flag data... ")
        a_flag.get_data()
        print("    got --> " + a_flag.buffer)
        print("  Getting r_flag data... ")
        r_flag.get_data()
        print("    got --> " + r_flag.buffer)
        if a_flag.is_answered() and r_flag.buffer:
            print("Set r_flag to ACQUIRED... ", end="")
            r_flag.set_stat([0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
            print("Done")
            buffer = a_flag.buffer
            del r_flag
            del a_flag
            del b_flag
            print("Returning buffer")
            return buffer
```

Here's what it outputs

```
Got a request: stat
Creating r_flag data... Done
Creating a_flag data... Done
Creating b_flag data... Done
Getting b_flag data... Done
Set r_flag to REQUESTED... Done
Now enter looping... Done
  Getting a_flag data...
```

As you can see it doesn't process pass a_flag.get_data() which is defined like below

```py
class Flag():

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.flag_f = f

    def __del__(self):
        self.flag_f.close()

    def get_data(self):
        self.rewind()
        self.buffer = self.flag_f.readline().split()
        return self.buffer

    def set_stat(self, data):
        self.rewind()
        for i in range(0, 8):
            self.flag_f.write("{0} ".format(data[i], end=""))

    def rewind(self):
        self.flag_f.seek(0)
```

I have absolutely no idea what's the problem (please note that it got data form b_flag correctly using the same function)

answer.flg

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

busy.flg

```
1 4 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

request.flg

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

please bear with my code

Comment: Something is missing here: `r_flag.set_stat([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])` would suggest that `Flag` has a method called `set_stat`, but that's not the case.

Comment: oops, sorry I must have missed it when I was copying. Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I run your code, I get the following error, which immediately reveals the issue:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-85d0a94e893a> in <module>
----> 1 get_answer()

<ipython-input-7-753bd9beab41> in get_answer()
     26         print("  Getting a_flag data... ")
     27         a_flag.get_data()
---> 28         print("    got --> " + a_flag.buffer)
     29         print("  Getting r_flag data... ")
     30         r_flag.get_data()

TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Changing the statement to e.g. `print("    got --> " + str(a_flag.buffer))` takes care of the issue, even if it's not the only one with the code: You'll have to do the same thing with `r_flag` a bit later, and even then, you'll run into the issue that you're using `is_answered` on `Flag` which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I'll take care of it, also is_answered is actually define in the full version of Flag, I should have mention it.